# Preventing codes being issued out twice

Tags: php, csv

I have a system where a client provides a whole bunch of random codes which are stored in a CSV file in 1 column. When a user submits a form they get issued one of these random codes. The issue is that this form gets submitted a lot, I mean a lot and sometimes in very quick succession. And what is occurring is the form submitters are sometimes being issued the same code.

The code at the moment looks like this:

```
$file = fopen($csv_relative_path, 'r');

// Iterate over it to get every line 
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    // Store every line in an array
    $data[] = $line;
}

fclose($file);

// Remove the first element from the stored array / first line of file being read
if(!empty($data)){

    $code = $data[0][0];

    array_shift($data);

    // Open file for writing
    $file = fopen($csv_relative_path, 'w');

    // Write remaining lines to file
    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($file, $fields);
    }
    fclose($file);

}
```

What is wrong with my code which is causing this to occur? Is the final stage looping through all the lines/codes and writing them to the file? How can I speed this code up or what methodology can I implement to prevent the same code being issued out multiple times?

Thanks,

Comment: Use a database instead? Where you can just mark one code as invalid without having to write the remaining codes to a file, that might take a long time

Comment: @brombeer thanks for your comment, so one constraint is that the client must use a CSV to at least store the codes. The file doesn't necessarily have to be updated though. However initially what I was doing was storing an array in the database of used codes, but that method was creating duplicate codes also because of the time to loop through the used codes in the database, so I went down this path instead. Is there a way to get the first line from the CSV without having to loop through every line like I am doing initially? Or another option?